# Yakuake is not restoring my appearance settings

Tags: shell, lxde, konsole

Yakuake is not restoring my appearance settings on startup. The settings are saved to disk, as far as I can tell with strace, is being read by Yakuake. However, Yakuake uses default settings nevertheless.

**Desktop:** LXQT 0.10

**WM:** Kwin

**Yakuake:** 3.0.2

*yakuakerc*

```
[Desktop Entry]
DefaultProfile=Profile 1.profile

[Dialogs]
FirstRun=false

[Favorite Profiles]
Favorites=

[Shortcuts]
close-active-terminal=Ctrl+Shift+R
close-session=Ctrl+Shift+W
decrease-window-height=Alt+Shift+Up
decrease-window-width=Alt+Shift+Left
file_quit=Ctrl+Shift+Q
grow-terminal-bottom=Ctrl+Alt+Down
grow-terminal-left=Ctrl+Alt+Left
grow-terminal-right=Ctrl+Alt+Right
grow-terminal-top=Ctrl+Alt+Up
increase-window-height=Alt+Shift+Down
increase-window-width=Alt+Shift+Right
move-session-left=Ctrl+Shift+Left
move-session-right=Ctrl+Shift+Right
new-session=Ctrl+Shift+T
next-session=Shift+Right
next-terminal=Ctrl+Shift+Down
previous-session=Shift+Left
previous-terminal=Ctrl+Shift+Up
rename-session=Ctrl+Alt+S
split-left-right=Ctrl+(
split-top-bottom=Ctrl+)
toggle-session-monitor-activity=Ctrl+Shift+A
toggle-session-monitor-silence=Ctrl+Shift+I
view-full-screen=Ctrl+Shift+F11
```

*Profile 1.profile*

```
[Appearance]
ColorScheme=DarkPastels

[General]
Name=Profile 1
Parent=FALLBACK/
```

Is this a known problem, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known bug in Konsole, see https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=364336. The workaround is either to copy the changes from ~/.local/share/yakuake/ to ~/.local/share/konsole/ or make the changes in the konsole program and save them.